# Only allow user to go to a page if he/she passes the validation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How can I prevent users from entering a specific page if they put a wrong value in VueJS?

For example I have this code snippet that I grabbed from my code that validates if user's  chosen date will match the date from my JSON.

```
checkBirthday: function() {
  //compare results birthday and input birthday
  let inputBDAY = moment(this.date).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
  if (this.results.BIRT_D == inputBDAY) {
    //redirect to details page
    this.$router.push("/details/" + this.MEMB_N);
  } else {
    alert("Wrong Birthday");
  }
}
```

This is my routes.js snippet

```
{
    path: '/details/:MEMB_N', component: details
},
```

I want only to redirect a page if the validation is true and prevent if false.

Right now:
I can access the page I want even if I don't validate the birthday

Comment: Is `this.date` being treated as a 'password' to access the member details?

Comment: sort of but it's kinda toy validation tho I just want to know how can I solve the problem I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Use navigation guards on the 'secure' page/component. Read [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)